# How to get different singleton in different module that create the same singleton in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I had study 「Beware of singleton in Flex modules」
in http://www.devahead.com/blog/2010/03/beware-of-singleton-in-flex-modules/
and a lot of information tell me that different module with different content,but in my case it doesn't work!
why the different module use the same static object? 
I'm trying to use module wide singleton,but it work like application wide singleton.
Can someone help me how to make module wide singleton.
the short code is like:

```
    <s:Application>
    <s:ModuleLoader id="A" creationComplete="loadAModule()"/>    
    <s:ModuleLoader id="B" creationComplete="loadBModule()"/>    

    </s:Application>

    //-----------AModule
    <s:Module>
       var aITx:ITx=Tx.newInstant();//Tx extend ITX
       tracc(aITx.instantId);
       ...
    </s:Module>

    //-----------BModule
    <s:Module>
       var aITx:ITx=Tx.getInstance();//Tx extend ITX
       tracc(aITx.instanceID);
       ...
    </s:Module>


    //-----singleton class
        public class Tx extends EventDispatcher  implements ITx
        {
            public function Tx()
            {
                // Add listeners
                addEventListeners();
            } 
            private static var instance:Tx;
            public static function getInstance():Tx
            {
                if (!instance)
                {
                    instance = new Tx();
                    // Generate a random instance ID
                    instance._instanceID = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                    trace("create new itx id="+instance.instanceID);
                }else{
                    trace("use old itx id="+instance.instanceID);
                }

                return instance;
            }
            protected var _instanceID: Number = NaN;

            public function get instanceID(): Number
            {
                return _instanceID;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to the context the modules are loaded in. In your case I guess all of your modules are loaded into the same context. In one context there is only one version of one class. Therefore there is only one instance of your Singleton. If you want to have separate classes, you have to load each module into its own context. Have a look at this link which explains the context stuff pretty good: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=05_Display_Programming_33.html

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right. But I've gave up to use singleton and to rewrite every thing . Now every thing is ok.